# How to display popup ad only once in any session

Tags: 6

I want to show popup ad once only no matter how many pages are visited by site visitor and the following code in `page.tpl.php` is causing to show ads more than once. How to correct it?:

```
<?php      
  $showadzedo = false;  
  if( !isset($_COOKIE['ad_zedo'])) { $showadzedo = true; setcookie('ad_zedo',1); }  
 ?> 
<?php
  if($showadzedo){      
?>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        var zflag_nid="1185"; var zflag_cid="3307"; var zflag_sid="823"; var zflag_width="1"; var zflag_height="1"; var zflag_sz="15";
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript" src="http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js"></script>

<?php            
  }
?>
```

I've tried placing cookie setting part to the very beginning of the `page.tpl.php` file and second part in the bottom before closure. But I still see ad popup more than once. How to make it work?

I've even tried `_SESSION['ad_zedo']` instead of setting/getting cookied but does not seem to work.

Comment: in first look logic seems to be ok, are you sure cookies are accepted by browser and are you able to check whether that cookie is set or not ?

Comment: yes @kantu  and I've checked with multiple browsers